# Setting up open wireless access point on Raspberry pi

Tags: hostapd, captive-portal

I have set up me Raspberry Pi as a wireless access point protected with WPA2 and a password but is there any way I can turn it into a open access point? Like changing my hostapd settings?

My hostapd.conf looks like this:

```
country_code=GB
interface=wlan0
ssid=NoWifi
hw_mode=a
channel=36
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=FreeWifi
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

I want to do this because I have set up a captive portal and I don't want users to fill in a password and also fill in info on my captive portal.

Answer (score 0):

To start with your access point can either be protected with WPA2 (or) open at a time. You can make the HostAP set to open mode and use any of the available open source captive portal implementation set to handle the traffic accordingly. There are many open source captive portal implementation available, I will leave it up to you to search and adapt which one makes sense for your particular requirement.